# Oracle APEX Dwonload blob content in button click

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table with blob_content which are pdf documents.

It is easy to create a interactive report with download links for each row. But I am trying to do this differently.

I am displaying only the document name in my interactive report. The user clicks the document and is taken to page6 where I am displayed other details about the document and have a button "Download".

I tried to create a download link according to what is given in http://joelkallman.blogspot.se/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html

I created application item, application process and a Dynamic Action (java script code) for the button where I have specified,

```
htp.p(APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':10:'|| :APP_SESSION
||'::NO::APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOCUMENT:::DOCID:' || :P6_PK_ID);
```

But this does nothing.

I know I am going wrong somewhere. I am unable to find any better help on Google in this area.

Can someone help?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - `htp.p` is not javascript code, and all your code does is print the URL directly. Perhaps you need to call `window.open(...)` instead.

Comment: In fact, you don't need a Dynamic Action at all - just render the URL as the target of a link/button.

Comment: Hi, I removed Dynamic Action and set it as "Redirect to URL". URL Target has "APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':10:'|| :APP_SESSION
||'::NO::APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOCUMENT:::DOCID:' || :P6_PK_ID"

Comment: Hi, I removed Dynamic Action and set it as "Redirect to URL". URL Target has "APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':10:'|| :APP_SESSION
||'::NO::APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOCUMENT:::DOCID:' || :P6_PK_ID"            When I executed the page, the url is formed as https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL%28p_url%20=%3E%20%27f?p=%27%20||%20:APP_ID%20||%20%27:10:%27||%20:APP_SESSION%0A%0A||%27::NO::APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOCUMENT:::DOCID:%27%20||%20:P6_PK_ID  Why is it not forming the right url. I am new to APEX. So, I am sure that I am doing something wrong somwhere..

Answer (score 0):

I saw your latest thread about download problem in Mobile application. Please put following code in plsql process:

```
DECLARE  
  l_url varchar2(2000); 
l_app number := v('APP_ID');
l_session number := v('APP_SESSION');
l_pk_id number := v('P14_PK_ID'); 
BEGIN  
  l_url := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(  
       'f?p=' || l_app || ':1:'|| l_session||':APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOC:::DOCID:'||l_pk_id ,p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');  
  htp.init();  
  apex_util.redirect_url(l_url, true);  
  apex_application.stop_apex_engine;  
END;
```

Put this code in plsql process which download your content.

### Edit

I put following code in Url to download content

```
javascript:location.href=('f?p=&APP_ID.:14:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETDOC:::DOCID:&P14_PK_ID.');
```

Comment: Hi Pars, I updated my code with what you suggested here. "htp.init();" and "apex_application.stop_apex_engine;" But still I am getting the same error message.

Comment: The problem is only in jQuey Smartphone page. It is working fine in Desktop page.

Comment: this code tested under Mobile application and it works for me in mobile application.

Comment: BEST way is create demo application over https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1

Comment: Hi, I already have a demo application in apex.oracle.com. This is where I am doing this app development. The details is as below. apex.oracle.com WS:umailango1 USERNAME: demo PASSWORD: demo123 The link to my app https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=63313:LOGIN_JQM_SMARTPHONE:16026032650164 Thanks in advance for your help. To test it, you can use the username: uilango & password demo123

Comment: CHECK YOUR APPLICATION PAGE 14, BUTTON "SOWNLOAD_PARS2_JS" WORK WELL AND DOWNLOAD THE FILE.

Comment: i edit my answer and put code which is used to download